# show efficiently database milion record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a database with 10 millions of records. The table is structured as:

Table name : record

- Filed1: Name (varchar)(Primary key)
- Field2: Record(int/bigint)(Index)

example:

```
Name | Record
Darrin | 256
Aaron | 3
Daryl | 12
...
```

**I want to create an html page that shows the ranking order by records like:**

-https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2016-10-30?sort=reputationchange&page=1

,but I have 2 problems:

- **the records are too many** (ORDER BY take 20 second to order table without LIMIT)
- **if I showed you a little at a time** (eg first page 0-100, second page 100-200 ...)
  **every page should invoke a query to sort the database like  :**
  first page:  "SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 0,100" second page:  "SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT
  100,100"

**This is very inefficient,and the time will increase a lot for the last query es :**

-first page:  "SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 0,100"**-->take 0.003 second**

-last page:"SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 10.000.000,100" **-->take 10 second**

it is best to keep the database ordered while I INSERT Record?

how can I do otherwise?

how does the StackOverflow page mentioned above to load so quickly?

Thank you!.

Comment: Your syntax is clearly not SQL Server, so I removed that tag.

Comment: Please explain _why_ you need the millionth row.

Comment: It would be able to show the ranking of most pages without using for the last queries many seconds, but using tenths of a second like the first. Similar to  http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2016-10-30?sort=reputationchange&page=1  (but with 10 milion rows)

Answer (score 0):

> -first page: "SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 0,100"-->take 0.003 second
>
> -last page:"SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 10.000.000,100" -->take 10 second

It's because of MySql touches 10.000.100 records for second request.

You need to replace index (Record) by complex index (Record, Name) and use this SQL instead of yours

`SELECT Name,Record FROM record WHERE (Record, Name) < (3, 'Aaron') ORDER BY Record DESC, Name DESC LIMIT 100`

for the first page and

`SELECT Name,Record FROM record WHERE (Record, Name) < (3, 'Aaron') ORDER BY Record DESC, Name DESC LIMIT 100`,

for next pages, where `(3, 'Aaron')` - values of fields (Record, Name) of last row on previous page.

Comment: thanks but how I run the first query ,  I do not know the value of (3, 'Aaron')

Comment: @John Sorry, first query

Comment: `SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC, Name DESC LIMIT 100`

Comment: As before the query works faster in the first query and slow in the last.

Comment: If i search  " SELECT Name,Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC, Name DESC LIMIT 100 " --> 0.003 second,

Comment: if i search "SELECT Name,Record FROM record WHERE (Record, Name) < (100, 'record100') ORDER BY Record DESC, Name DESC LIMIT 100"-->10 second

Comment: i had: primary index--> name , index -->(Record,Name).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - using of subsequences:

```
SELECT r.Name, r.Record FROM record r JOIN (
  SELECT Record FROM record ORDER BY Record DESC LIMIT 10000000,100
) q ON q.Record = r.Record
```

See this article -
[MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

Comment: Late-row-lookup avoids reaching into the record, but does not avoid touching 10,000,100 rows of the index.